# Dragging Ellipse over an image

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, svg

Good afternoon
I am trying to find a way to allow an ellipse (dot) move over an image area only (canvas) and find a way to retrieve the coordinate to store in a database in order to retrieve it later on and be able to redraw the ellipse without being draggable.

Right now, I have a rectangle instead of a dot, the rectangle is not limited to the image area and I am not sure how I can retrieve the coordinate of it to store it using asp.net core MVC.
Thank you.

```js
//Make the DIV element draggagle:
dragElement(document.getElementById("mydiv"));

function dragElement(elmnt) {
  var pos1 = 0,
    pos2 = 0,
    pos3 = 0,
    pos4 = 0;
  if (document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header")) {
    /* if present, the header is where you move the DIV from:*/
    document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header").onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  } else {
    /* otherwise, move the DIV from anywhere inside the DIV:*/
    elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  }

  function dragMouseDown(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
    // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
    document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
  }

  function elementDrag(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // calculate the new cursor position:
    pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
    pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    // set the element's new position:
    elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
    elmnt.style.left = (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
  }

  function closeDragElement() {
    /* stop moving when mouse button is released:*/
    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;
  }
}
```

```css
#mydiv {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
}

#mydivheader {
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: move;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<p>Click and hold the mouse button down while moving the Ellipse element</p>

<svg viewBox="0 0 400 400" width="400" height="400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <g>
    <image stroke="null" xlink:href="https://www.pngkey.com/png/full/8-80588_car-cartoon-png-group-picture-pollution-voiture-png.png" id="svg_1" height="400" width="400" y="0" x="0"/>
  </g>
  <div id="mydiv">
    <div id="mydivheader">
      <g data-id="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" class="draggable">
        <ellipse class="0" cx="3" cy="3" rx="3" ry="3" style=""></ellipse>
      </g>
    </div>
  </div>
</svg>
```

Comment: What are you stuck at?  You have the coordinates of the "ellipse" (clientX and clientY).  All you need to do is store those in a database. Then retrieve those later and position ellipses at those coordinates.  Are you stuck at the database part (storing and retrieving). Or are you stuck at adding elements after retrieving?  Or something else?

Comment: Right now, I have a rectangle instead of a dot/ellipse (1), the rectangle is not limited to the image area (2) and I am not sure how I can retrieve the coordinate of it to store it (3)

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the build-in [HTML Drag and Drop API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API)? In your markup you mix HTML and SVG – that is why the ellipse does not show up. The logic is fine, but I think it makes sense to use drag and drop.

If the image of the car needs to be replaced by an SVG don't mix up the ellipse with that SVG.

The style of the `div#drop` has the property `position:relative`. That is on purpose – it is important if you move the `div#drop` to some other position in the document.

### Update

I changed the way that the relative position (relX,relY) is calculated. It now uses [Element.getBoundingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect). I also replaced `e.layerX/Y` with `e.offsetX/Y`.

```js
//Make the DIV element draggagle:
var mydiv = document.getElementById("mydiv");
var drop = document.getElementById("drop");

mydiv.addEventListener('dragstart', e => {
  let data = JSON.stringify({
    id: e.target.id,
    x: e.offsetX,
    y: e.offsetY
  });
  e.dataTransfer.setData("text/plain", data);
});

drop.addEventListener('dragover', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "move";
});

drop.addEventListener('drop', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let data = JSON.parse(e.dataTransfer.getData("text/plain"));
  let mydiv = document.getElementById(data.id);
  let dropRect = drop.getBoundingClientRect();
  let relX = e.clientX - data.x - dropRect.x;
  let relY = e.clientY - data.y - dropRect.y;
  console.log('relative pos:', `${relX},${relY}`);
  mydiv.style.left = `${relX}px`;
  mydiv.style.top = `${relY}px`;
});
```

```css
body {
  /* Padding added just to show that
  *  using getBoundingClientRect() is working.
  */
  
  padding: 10px 0 0 20px;
}

#drop {
  position: relative;
}

#mydiv {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: move;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

#mydiv ellipse {
  fill: green;
}
```

```html
<p>Click and hold the mouse button down while moving the Ellipse element</p>

<div id="drop">
  <img src="https://www.pngkey.com/png/full/8-80588_car-cartoon-png-group-picture-pollution-voiture-png.png" width="400" />
  <div id="mydiv" draggable="true">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 6 6" width="20" height="20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <g data-id="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" class="draggable">
        <ellipse cx="3" cy="3" rx="3" ry="3" />
      </g>
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

### Update

OP ask if the position of the ellipse can be updated using form inputs. In the following example I added a form for updating the values. The values of the form will also update when the ellipse is moved around.

```js
//Make the DIV element draggagle:
var mydiv = document.getElementById("mydiv");
var drop = document.getElementById("drop");

mydiv.addEventListener('dragstart', e => {
  let data = JSON.stringify({
    id: e.target.id,
    x: e.offsetX,
    y: e.offsetY
  });
  e.dataTransfer.setData("text/plain", data);
});

drop.addEventListener('dragover', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "move";
});

drop.addEventListener('drop', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let data = JSON.parse(e.dataTransfer.getData("text/plain"));
  let mydiv = document.getElementById(data.id);
  let dropRect = drop.getBoundingClientRect();
  let relX = e.clientX - data.x - dropRect.x;
  let relY = e.clientY - data.y - dropRect.y;
  // update the form values
  let form = document.forms.form01;
  form.x.value = relX;
  form.y.value = relY;
  // update the position of the ellipse
  mydiv.style.left = `${relX}px`;
  mydiv.style.top = `${relY}px`;
});

document.forms.form01.addEventListener('change', e => {
  let form = e.target.form;
  let x = parseInt(form.x.value);
  let y = parseInt(form.y.value);
  // update the position of the ellipse
  mydiv.style.left = `${x}px`;
  mydiv.style.top = `${y}px`;
});
```

```css
body {
  /* Padding added just to show that
  *  using getBoundingClientRect() is working.
  */
  
  padding: 10px 0 0 20px;
}

#drop {
  position: relative;
}

#mydiv {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: move;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

#mydiv ellipse {
  fill: green;
}
```

```html
<p>Click and hold the mouse button down while moving the Ellipse element OR input X anf Y values in the form (and hit enter):</p>
<form name="form01">
<label>X: <input name="x" type="text"/></label>
<label>Y: <input name="y" type="text"/></label>
</form>

<div id="drop">
  <img src="https://www.pngkey.com/png/full/8-80588_car-cartoon-png-group-picture-pollution-voiture-png.png" width="400" />
  <div id="mydiv" draggable="true">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 6 6" width="20" height="20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <g data-id="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" class="draggable">
        <ellipse cx="3" cy="3" rx="3" ry="3" />
      </g>
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It works well, but using bootstrap inside a  <div class="card-body">  and inside a tab <div class="tab-content"> the ellipse goes totally out of control. I am not sure why.

Comment: It is probably because the container/parent element (in my example `<div id="drop">`) is not positioned relative (or absolute). Setting the a element to `position: relative` the clientX and clientY values for child elements will be relative to that.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion - unfortunately changing  #mydiv {
        position: relative; did not work for that case.

Comment: `#mydiv` is the element that you move around – it is the parent element of `#mydiv` that needs to be styled `position: relative`.

Comment: I put a code snippet here for ex: https://codepen.io/lbrettsinclair/pen/RwMPwVO - I am not getting it :( - sorry

Comment: In the codepen example, the only thing that you need to change is that `#mydiv` should be positioned absolute: `position: absolute;`. OK, so the element that you move around should be positioned absolute and the parent element should be positioned relative.

Comment: Turns out that the Nav bar and the Side bar are changing the behavior somehow.

Comment: @lbrettsinclair I can see the problem and have updated my answer. Notice `let dropRect = drop.getBoundingClientRect();` and the following lines and the use of `x: e.offsetX, y: e.offsetY` where I set up the data object.

Comment: So I added 2 input elements to store the X and Y values. But when I read the values and assign them to the 2 input, the ellipse is out of place. Thank you so much for all the help with this !

Comment: I extended the question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73046780/dragging-ellipse-over-an-image-storing-and-retrieving-position-values/73047708#73047708 as I could not find a way to make it work when reading the data from the DB.

Comment: @lbrettsinclair I updated my answer with a second example.

Comment: when I save the data using my controller, model.Body_Injury.Body_PosX is always zero. The difference with your code is that I use MVC
`code`
<div>
<input type="text" asp-for="@Model.Body_Injury.Body_PosX"  class="form-control" name="x">
<input type="text" asp-for="@Model.Body_Injury.Body_PosY"  class="form-control" name="y">
</div>
`code`

Comment: sorry to bother again, I really appreciate your help so far. Would you happen to know why when I use the asp-for it is not working ?

Comment: @lbrettsinclair I'm sorry. I don't know asp that well, but I don't think you need the input elements. Try printing out the value from the backed/db directly in a JavaScript element. Something like `mydiv.style.left = [here goes value from backed]px;`. This is after `mydiv` is loaded and defined.